# Spawning multiple child processes to preview Vue.js projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, vue.js

**Context:**
I'm making a Codepen-like app but I want it to support sophisticated JS libraries/frameworks like Vue or Angular 2+ for example. I want to have a live preview of my snippet which updates in a reasonable time. So I came up with an idea that when I create a new snippet I'll initialize a *blank* starter project on my backend server and run `npm start` to have [Hot reload](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/hot-reload.html) enabled. When I update the code of my snippet on the frontend side, I'm making a request to the backend server and update files in the starter project which is making the *Hot reload* refresh the live preview. This is what I got at the moment and it is working.

**What I came up with:**
This is my function which first copies the starter project to the new location, searches for the free port and eventually spawns `npm start`:

```
function createStarter(request, snippetId, callback) {

    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const portfinder = require('portfinder');
    const { technology } = request.params;

    const snippetPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../static/snippets/vue', snippetId.toString());

    spawnProcess('cp', ['-r', 'vue-starter/', snippetPath], { cwd: snippetPath.slice(0, snippetPath.lastIndexOf('/')) })
        .then(async () => {

            const lastPort = process.env.STARTER_LAST_USED_PORT || 1e4;
            const port = await portfinder.getPortPromise({ port: +lastPort + 1 }).catch(console.error);
            process.env.STARTER_LAST_USED_PORT = port;

            const packageJson = require(`${snippetPath}/package.json`);
            packageJson.scripts.dev += ` --port ${port}`;

            fs.writeFileSync(`${snippetPath}/package.json`, JSON.stringify(packageJson), 'utf8');

            console.log(`Starting project ${snippetId} at port ${port}`);

            spawnProcess('npm', ['start'], { cwd: snippetPath });
        })
        .catch(console.error);

    callback();
}
```

where `spawnProcess()` is just a simple helper which executes `spawn(...args)` and binds events to the streams.

**Actual question:**
Is it a good idea to have multiple child processes spawned in parallel? I'm not worried about `cp -r` from the function above because it's short command and lasts for a few seconds. What I am worried about is `npm start` which potentially can last for even hours and I'm wondering if this is a good practice to spawn potentially, say, 50 or 100 child processes with `npm start` running for a long time before it'll be killed. I was thinking about setting a timeout for this command and kill it after about a minute but it can cause another issue which is re-spawning a child process multiple times which requires more resources.